# VaultCustomQueryCriteria for State in Corda

Tags: corda

I am trying to query a state from vault without using the linear Id of the state and instead an Int(unique) variable present in Schema

```
val sNumber = AState.ASchemaV1.AEntity::SNumber
val QueryCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(sNumber.equal(SalesNumber))
val StateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<AState>(QueryCriteria).states.single()
val outState = StateAndRef.state.data
```

The Query criteria is not throwing any error but I am also not getting any output but on debugging I got an error response

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity: AState.ASchemaV1.AEntity
```

but I have defined all the columns in the function. What am I missing?
Here is code for Schema

```
    override fun supportedSchemas() = listOf(ASchemaV1)
    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema) = ASchemaV1.AEntity(this)

    object ASchemaV1 : MappedSchema(AState::class.java, 1, listOf(AEntity::class.java)) {
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "Table")
        class AEntity(A: AState) : PersistentState() {
            @Column
            var CONumber: String = A.linearId.id.toString()
            @Column
            var SalesNumber: Int = A.SalesNumber
            @Column
            var ProductID: Int = A.ProductID
            @Column
            var Quantity: Int = A.Quantity
            @Column
            var Rate: Double = A.Rate
            @Column
            var DeliveryDate: Date = A.DeliveryDate
            @Column
            var DeliveryLocation: String = A.DeliveryLocation
            @Column
            var Status: String = A.Status.toString()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for AState.ASchemaV1?

Comment: The schema code is not in separate file instead is made as a object in state data class

Answer (score 1):

AState.ASchemaV1 is missing the constructor.

```
object ASchemaV1 : MappedSchema(AState::class.java, 1, listOf(AEntity::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Table")
    class AEntity(
        @Column
        var CONumber: String,
        @Column
        var SalesNumber: Int,
        @Column
        var ProductID: Int,
        @Column
        var Quantity: Int,
        @Column
        var Rate: Double,
        @Column
        var DeliveryDate: Date,
        @Column
        var DeliveryLocation: String,
        @Column
        var Status: String
    ): PersistentState() {
       constructor(A: AState): this(A.linearId.id.toString(), A.SalesNumber, A.ProductID, A.Quantity, A.Rate, A.DeliveryDate, A.DeliveryLocation, A.Status.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it already have a constructor with the state. Why would I need to explicitly define the columns in the primary constructor?

Comment: It didnt work and doest kotlin jpa generate a default constructor